# Adjusting Tab Width in Material UI App Bar

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, tabs, material-ui, appbar

I am pretty new to Material UI, but it is super cool! However, I would like to decrease the width of each tab panel/label, so all three labels appear at once.

Notice how the last label, Upload, is currently falling off of the sidebar.
[image]

I based my AppBar based on [this one](https://material-ui.com/api/app-bar/#appbar-api) from Material UI. Any suggestions?

I am basically trying to decreasing the spacing in an example like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/lmokg) between "Page One", "Page Two", and "Page Three"

Comment: Can you share us a functional codesandbox ?

Comment: @gionic it is pretty much this https://codesandbox.io/s/lmokg - I want to decrease the spacing between "Page One", "Page Two", and "Page Three"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough points to comment, but if you notice your codeSandbox, the `<Tabs />` component adjusts correctly to the width available.

Your problem can be:

1. the parent component has `overflow` and lets the `<Tabs />` grow more than you expect.
2. there isn’t enough space for the tabs to grow equally, so per material ui spec they should be scrollable.

You can try to decrease the tabs padding with the [CSS API](https://material-ui.com/api/tab/#css) or respect the spec. I advise the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove from `<Tabs>` the property of `variant="fullWidth"` . And you can add a `className` at your `<LinkTab className={classes.customTab}`

Then you can add whatever width you want at your `useStyles` as `minWidth`.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  customTab: {
    minWidth: 50
  }
}));
```

Check the example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-wuh1b)